# Jquery validate change required value when submit form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-validate

I want to change required value in jquery validate from false to true and true to false.

if textbxox1 is empty i would like to set gobalvar=true else gobalvar=false,

but in jquery validate from not change value. it remember only true value.

How to solve ?

PHP code:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1"   method="post">
      <input type='text' id='textbox1' name='textbox1'/>
      <input type='text' id='textbox2' name='textbox2'/>
      <input type='submit' value='submit' id='save' name='save'/>
</form>
```

my js

```
   var gobalvar=true;

    if($('#textbox1').val()==""){
        gobalvar=true;
    }else{
        gobalvar=false;
    }
    alert(gobalvar);
    $("#from1").validate({ 
    rules: {
        textbox2:{required:gobalvar}, 
               },
        messages: {
        textbox2:'required'
        }
});​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($('#textbox1').val()==""){
                   // ^------missing brackets
        gobalvar=true;
    }else{
        gobalvar=false;
    }
```

Also your form id is different from your jquery selector

```
    var gobalvar=true;

    if($('#textbox1').val()==""){
        gobalvar=true;
    }else{
        gobalvar=false;
    }

    $("#form1").validate({ 
      //^----different selector value
    rules: {
        textbox2:{required:gobalvar}, 
               },
        messages: { //missing semicolon
        textbox2:'required'
        }
});​
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ujLy/)

## [Update 2](http://jsfiddle.net/6ujLy/2/)

Comment: i change form name already still not working. i think the problem is jquery validate cannot change value.

Comment: Dear your demo when false condition is not working, when textbox1 is not empty, it should hidden error message .

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
    var gobalvar=true;

    $("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        textbox2:{required:(globalvar = ($("#textbox1").val().length == 0))},
               },
             message{textbox2:'required'}
});
```